# Working on windows for IOS application on Unity 3D

Tags: windows, macos, ios, ubuntu-unity, unity3d

I am new to Unity 3D. So I am trying to develop some AR project on my windows machine for IOS App. In asset store I couldn't have found ARKit plugin but I have to import arkit plugin to my project.

So what should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ARKit](https://developer.apple.com/arkit/) is a framework that runs exclusively under macOS with Xcode. You therefore need to run macOS to be able to use ARKit. It cannot be used under Windows.